Weak law of large numbers for weak $L^1$ random variables
A scalar random variable ${X}$ is said to be in weak ${L^1}$ if one has
$\displaystyle  \sup_{t>0} t {\bf P}(|X| \geq t) < \infty$.
Thus Markov’s inequality tells us that every absolutely integrable random variable is in weak ${L^1}$, but the converse is not true (e.g. random variables with the Cauchy distribution are weak ${L^1}$ but not absolutely integrable). Show that if ${X_1,X_2,\dots}$ are iid copies of an unsigned weak ${L^1}$ random variable that is not almost surely zero, then there exists quantities ${a_n \rightarrow \infty}$ such that ${S_n/a_n}$ converges in probability to ${1}$, where ${S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n}$.
Attempt: Feller gave a necessary and sufficient condition for the relative stability of $S_n$ in this non-degenerate non-negative iid variables setting, see Theorem $2$, p. $236$ of An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications.
Focusing only on the case where $X$ is non-integrable, we imitate Feller's proof for sufficiency and use a truncation argument to split $X_i = X_{i, \leq M} + X_{i, > M}$ for some parameter $M > 0$ to be chosen later, where $X_{i, \leq M} := X1_{X_i \leq M}$ and $X_{i, > M} := X1_{X_i > M}$. Correspondingly $S_n = S_{n, \leq} + S_{n, >}$, with the subscripts $\leq$ and $>$ indicating the $n$th partial sums of the $X_{i, \leq M}$ and $X_{i, > M}$, resp. Denote by $F$ the CDF of $X$.
The random variable $X1_{X \leq M}$ has mean ${\bf E}(X1_{X \leq M}) = \mu(M)$ (which clearly tends to infinity as $M \to \infty$), and variance
$\displaystyle {\bf Var}(X1_{X \leq M}) \leq {\bf E}X^21_{X \leq M} = \int_{0}^M 2x(1 - F(x))\ dx = \int_{0}^M 2x{\bf P}(X > x)\ dx \leq 2CM$, where $C =  \sup_{t>0} t {\bf P}(X \geq t)$.
By Chebyshev’s inequality, we thus have $\displaystyle {\bf P}(|\frac{S_{n, <}}{n} - \mu(M)| \geq \lambda) \leq \frac{2MC}{n \lambda^2}$ for any $\lambda > 0$. Meanwhile, the random variable ${X 1_{X > M}}$ is only nonzero with probability ${\bf P}(X > M) \leq C/M$, so $S_{n, >}$ is nonzero with probability at most $nC/M$. We conclude that
$\displaystyle {\bf P}(|\frac{S_n}{n} - \mu(M)| \geq \lambda) \leq \frac{2MC}{n \lambda^2} + \frac{nC}{M}$, valid for any $\lambda, M > 0$.
Set $\lambda = \varepsilon \mu(M)$, and further introduce the notation $M = M(n) = b_n$, we get
$\displaystyle {\bf P}(|\frac{S_n}{n\mu(b_n)} - 1| \geq \varepsilon) \leq \frac{2b_nC}{n \varepsilon^2 \mu^2(b_n)} + nO(\frac{1}{b_n})$.
One therefore aims to choose the truncation parameter $M = b_n$ obeying $(1). b_n = o(n\mu^2(b_n))$ and $(2). n = o(b_n)$. Per condition $(2)$, we tentatively set $b_n = nr(n)$ for some $r(n) \to \infty$. If we pick $r(n)$ with $\mu(nr(n))/r(n) \geq 1$ for large $n$, then in particular $b_n \leq n\mu(b_n)$ and condition $(1)$ is met. The result thus holds with $a_n = n\mu(b_n)$.
Question: One can show that the function $\mu(s)/s$ is right continuous and tends to zero as $s \to \infty$ (with a decay rate of $O(\log s/s)$). As such, Feller chose the norming sequence $a_n = n\mu(b_n)$ to be the unique solution to $n\mu(b_n) = b_n$. Is the argument above correct? Or is there a different, possibly non-constructive way to show the existence of the parameters $b_n$ obeying $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Update: The author of the problem hinted that if the expectation is infinite, setting the truncation parameter $b_n = n$ works. After some consideration, I came up with the following approach, with the same notations as the OP:
By the the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem: almost surely, one has
$\displaystyle \frac{1}{n} |\{ 1 \leq i \leq n: X_i \leq t \}| \rightarrow {\bf P}( X \leq t )$ uniformly in ${t}$ as ${n \rightarrow \infty}$.
On the other hand, ${\bf P}(X \leq t) = 1 - {\bf P}(X > t) \geq 1 - C/t$. So almost surely, for sufficiently large $n$, one has $|\{ 1 \leq i \leq n: X_i \leq t \}| \geq n(1 - C/t)$, or equivalently $|\{ 1 \leq i \leq n: X_i > t \}| \leq nC/t$. Setting $t = n$, we see that almost surely, for sufficiently large $n$, one has $|\{ 1 \leq i \leq n: X_i > n \}| \leq C$. Following the same line of argument as above, one obtains
$\displaystyle {\bf P}(|\frac{S_n}{n\mu(n)} - 1| \geq \varepsilon) \leq \frac{2C}{\varepsilon^2 \mu^2(n)} + C^2/n$
Sending $n \to \infty$ gives the claim.
Again, verifications are welcomed.
